# AD: No TGT after logon

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos

I’m investigating a domain where logon does not seem to produce a TGT.

After logon with a test account, `klist tgt` outputs this:

```
Current LogonId is 0:0x71647be1
Error calling API LsaCallAuthenticationPackage (Ticket Granting Ticket substatus): 1312

klist failed with 0x8009030e/-2146893042: No credentials are available in the security package
```

I. e. the same output you get on a non-domain member. However, the hosts are
definitely joined just that they seem to fall back on NTLM to authenticate to
services. DNS is set up correctly. In fact, *it is possible to obtain service
tickets manually* using `klist get $SPN`, even without being asked for
preauth credentials. So Kerberos as such seems functional, just that
applications like IE refuse to use it.

Likewise, `klist tickets` yields zero cached tickets. `klist sessions`
spits out errors of the form “Error calling API LsaGetLogonSessionData on
LogonId”.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this? Suggestions what I should check?

This is not a domain I have control over. The behavior is the same when logged
on directly to the machine and when connecting through RDP. Note though that
apparently this domain has grown over decades, probably even goes back to an
NT4 domain originally. I wonder whether at some point years ago they disabled Kerberos
auth for the whole domain (via GPO?) because it caused interop issues and then
forgot about it.

Comment: Does Wireshark show the clients _trying_ to get a TGT, or do they skip Kerberos entirely? Has the domain ever had the krbtgt key changed? Does it issue AES-based tickets (both the krbtgt and the service tickets; both the service key and the session key) or are any of them perhaps stuck with arcfour or even des3?

Comment: Sorry, I have no access to the domain and getting the person in charge to do a packet capture is going to take some effort. Yes, when I acquired the TGS manually, both the TGT and the TGS were AES (ticket encryption and the encrypted key). I think it’s a 2012-ish functional level domain. Kerberos itself appears to be working just fine.